# Boost::spirit::qi defining a calculator for nullaries

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to write a parser for math expressions where named variables are nullaries in `boost::spirit` (version 1_51_0), to which I'm completely new.  I define `typedef boost::function<double()> Value` and my rules will be declared like so: `qi::rule<Iterator, Value()> expression, term, others, ...;`

I define binary operators on nullaries with this macro

```
#define BINARY_FUNCTOR(name, op)                        \
struct name                                             \
{                                                       \
  name(Value x, Value y): x_(x), y_(y) {}               \
  double operator()() { return x_() op y_(); }          \
  Value x_, y_;                                         \
};
```

and have `ADD`, `SUB`, etc.  From the examples I've seen, I'd expect the rules to be defined like this:

```
expression = term
             >> *( (lit('+') >> term[ADD(_val, _1)])
                 | (lit('-') >> term[SUB(_val, _1)])
                 );
```

but that doesn't seem to be the right syntax, as I get an error

```
boost/spirit/home/support/action_dispatch.hpp:162: error: no match for call to ‘(const<unnamed>::SUB) (boost::function<double ()()>&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<boost::function<double ()()>&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, bool&)’
SRParser.cpp:38: note: candidates are: double<unnamed>::SUB::operator()()
```

which looks to me like `_1` isn't quite what I expect it to be, namely the `Value` associated with the next term.  What's the right syntax to define a rule like this?

Comment: It's not about syntax here, as much as it is about semantics. Actually, semantic actions. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/action.html for documentation on what is expected between `[` and `]`. See my answer for a working demo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser expression looks okay.

What you are confused over is on constructing the AST. Apparently, you have decided to use Semantic Actions to do so, but your effort is too sketchy for me to see just how (or even decide what sample you are basing this on).

In essence: What is it that you want to *do* with the instances of 'ADD'/'SUB' that you seem to *magically* "will" into your rules?

Right now, you just *use* the instance *directly* as a semantic action. This leads to the error message shown, which tells you, directly, that the instance is *not valid* as a semantic action.

I assume you really wanted to use Phoenix assignment to assign the binary operation to the exposed attribute, instead. This looks like:

```
expression = term
     >> *( (lit('+') >> term[ _val = phx::construct<ADD>(_val, _1)])
         | (lit('-') >> term[ _val = phx::construct<SUB>(_val, _1)])
         );
```

You'll see this matches much more closely with traditional expression grammars.

For fun I adapted a complete expression parser based on your `Value` type and created this working demonstration: **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kgPJR$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kgPJR%240)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

typedef std::function<double()> Value;

#define BINARY_FUNCTOR(name, op)                        \
struct name                                             \
{                                                       \
  name(Value x, Value y): x_(x), y_(y) {}               \
  double operator()() { return x_() op y_(); }          \
  Value x_, y_;                                         \
}; 

BINARY_FUNCTOR(ADD, +)
BINARY_FUNCTOR(SUB, -)
BINARY_FUNCTOR(MUL, *)
BINARY_FUNCTOR(DIV, /)

struct LIT
{
  LIT(double x): x_(x) {}
  double operator()() { return x_; }
  double x_;
}; 

struct NEG
{
  NEG(Value x): x_(x) {}
  double operator()() { return -x_(); }
  Value x_;
}; 


template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, Value(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(expression)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        expression =
            term                    [_val = _1]
            >> *( ('+' >> term  [_val = phx::construct<ADD>(_val, _1)])
                | ('-' >> term  [_val = phx::construct<SUB>(_val, _1)])
                );

        term =
            factor                [_val = _1]
            >> *( ('*' >> factor  [_val = phx::construct<MUL>(_val, _1)])
                | ('/' >> factor  [_val = phx::construct<DIV>(_val, _1)])
                );

        factor =
            double_               [_val = phx::construct<LIT>(_1)]
            |   '(' >> expression [_val = _1] >> ')'
            |   ('-' >> factor    [_val = phx::construct<NEG>(_1)])
            |   ('+' >> factor    [_val = _1]);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expression);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(term);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(factor);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Value(), Skipper> expression, term, factor;
};

Value doParse(const std::string& input)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    parser<It, qi::space_type> p;
    Value eval;

    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    if (!qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,eval))
        std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    if (f!=l) 
        std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    return eval;
}

int main()
{
    auto area = doParse("2 * (3.1415927 * (10*10))");
    std::cout << "Area of a circle r=10: " << area() << "\n";
}
```

It will print

```
Area of a circle r=10: 628.319
```

Comment: That does seem to be exactly what I was looking to do. Your working sample is almost exactly what I was doing, except for missing the variable look ups and I used `boost::lambda::constant` instead of your LIT struct!