# Boost spirit permutation of rules

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

I have 2 type of expressions that I want parse and calculate the results.

- Artimetic expressions: +,-,*,/ and sqrt() function;
  Ex: "2 + 3 * sqrt(100*25)"  ->  should be calculated as 152
- Functions: GetSubString() and ConcatenateStrings()
  Ex: "GetSubString('100str1', 0, 3)"  ->  should be calculated as 100

I have 2 seperate grammars to parse these expression types. Now I want to combine these 2 grammars and make it possible to define these expressions together.

Ex:

- "GetSubString('100str1', 0, 2+1) + sqrt(9)"   -> result= 103
- "2 + 3 * sqrt(GetSubString('100str1', 0, 2+1))"   -> result= 32

I have tried to combine 2 grammars as below by using permutation operator. But it doesnt compile.

```
    expr_    =
        ( *( (function_call_ ^ arithmeticexpression_)| string_ ));
```

So is this a right way to combine my function_call_ and arithmeticexpression_ rules or how should I do this?

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, double, std::wstring> RetValue;


RetValue CTranslationFunctions::GetSubString(RetValue const& str, RetValue position, RetValue len)
{
    std::wstring strToCut;
    size_t posInt = 0;
    size_t lenInt = 0;

    try
    {
        strToCut = boost::get<std::wstring>(str);
        posInt = boost::get<int>(position);
        lenInt = boost::get<int>(len);
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_get&)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return strToCut.substr(posInt, lenInt);
}

RetValue CTranslationFunctions::ConcatenateStrings(RetValue const& a, RetValue const& b) 
{
    wostringstream woss;
    woss << a << b;
    return woss.str();
}

double CTranslationFunctions::Negate(double num)
{
    return -num;
}

double CTranslationFunctions::Add(double num1 , const double num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
};

double CTranslationFunctions::Subtruct(double num1 , double num2)
{
    return num1 - num2;
};

double CTranslationFunctions::Multiply(double num1 , double num2)
{
    return num1 * num2;
};

double CTranslationFunctions::Divide(double num1 , double num2)
{
    return num1 / num2;
};

double CTranslationFunctions::Sqrt(double num)
{
    return sqrt(num);
}

class InvalidParamEx{};

double CTranslationFunctions::ConvertStringToDouble(RetValue val)
{
    wostringstream wss;
    double dNum;
    wss << val;
    std::wistringstream iss;
    iss.str(wss.str());
    try
    {
        iss >> dNum;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw InvalidParamEx();
    }

    return dNum;
}


BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(RetValue, ConcatenateStrings_, ConcatenateStrings, 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(RetValue, GetContainerId_, GetContainerId, 2)

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, Add_, Add, 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, Subtruct_, Subtruct, 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, Multiply_, Multiply, 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, Divide_, Divide, 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, Negate_, Negate, 1)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, Sqrt_, Sqrt, 1)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(double, ConvertStringToDouble_, ConvertStringToDouble, 1)

// Grammar to parse map functions
template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type >
struct MapFunctionParser : qi::grammar<It, RetValue(), Skipper, qi::locals<char>  >
{
    MapFunctionParser() : MapFunctionParser::base_type(expr_)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        function_call_ = 

        | (lit(L"GetSubString") > '(' > expr_ > ',' > expr_ > ',' > expr_ > ')')               
            [ _val = GetSubString_(_1, _2, _3) ]
        | (lit(L"ConcatenateStrings") > '(' > expr_ > lit(',') > expr_ > ')')               
            [ _val = ConcatenateStrings_(_1, _2) ];


        string_ = as_wstring[omit    [ char_("'\"") [_a =_1] ]        
        >> no_skip [ *(char_ - char_(_a))  ]
        >> lit(_a)];

        arithmeticexpression_ =
            term_                        [_val = _1]
        >>  *( ('+' >> term_           [_val = Add_(_val,_1)])
             |   ('-' >> term_           [_val = Subtruct_(_val, _1)])
            );

        term_ =
            factor_              [_val = _1]
        >> *( ('*' >> factor_  [_val = Multiply_(_val, _1)])
            |   ('/' >> factor_  [_val = Divide_(_val, _1)])
            );

        factor_ =
            double_                            [_val = _1]
          string_                            [_val = ConvertStringToDouble(_1)]
      |   ('-' >> factor_                  [_val = Negate_(_1)])
      |   ('+' >> factor_                  [_val = _1])
        |   (L"Sqrt" > '(' > double_ > ')'  )     [_val = Sqrt_(_1)]);


        expr_    =
            ( *( (function_call_ ^ arithmeticexpression_)| string_ ));


        on_error<fail> ( expr_, std::cout
            << phx::val("Error! Expecting ") << _4 << phx::val(" here: \"")
            << phx::construct<std::string>(_3, _2) << phx::val("\"\n"));

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(function_call_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expr_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(string_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(funcparameter_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(arithmeticexpression_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(factor_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(term_);
    }

private:
    qi::rule<It, RetValue(), Skipper, qi::locals<char> > function_call_, expr_, funcparameter_;
    qi::rule<It, wstring(), Skipper, qi::locals<char> > string_;
    qi::rule<It, double(), Skipper> arithmeticexpression_, factor_,  term_;
};
```

Comment: I ended up doing a rewrite of your grammar, using your samples as a guide for the grammar. I have provided a detailed walkthrough of my findings/changes. For the future: When asking for help, you really should try to post code that _compiles_ (except maybe the problem area).

Comment: Hah. Apparently [this was brought to your attention before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778399/boost-spirit-compile-issue#comment24178396_16778399)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** *Moved my early response to the bottom*

## **BIG UPDATE**

That took a while. Mostly it was because the code shown has strange problems:

- several rules contain syntax errors (`function_call` and `factor_`
- there is a reference to `GetContainerId` and `GetSubstring` was never Phoenix-adapted
- The type `CTranslationFunctions` didn't exist, and member functions were being declared
- however the ADAPT_FUNCTION macros *still* referenced the member function names *as if they were supposed to be in the enclosing namespace* (?!)

So what I basically ended up doing was a re-write. Yeah I know. I'm crazy. Nevertheless, let me walk you through it, explaining some of the things I changed and why.

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/function/adapt_function.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

typedef boost::variant<int, double>               NumValue;
typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::wstring> GenericValue;
```

Right away, I split the concept of *numeric* and *generic* values. This is because the distinction is important to certain expressions (mainly the *arithmetic expressions*). I could have still used `GenericValue` everywhere, but we'll see later how `NumValue` makes handling the arithmetic evaluations simpler.

```
struct InvalidParamEx : public virtual std::exception 
{
    const char* what() const noexcept { return "Invalid type of operand/parameter"; }
};
```

There's your exception type, showing some good practices. We throw it when a numeric value was expected, but the `GenericValue` contained something incompatible. How? Let's see:

```
struct AsNumValue : boost::static_visitor<NumValue>
{
    int      operator()(int i)                 const { return i; }
    double   operator()(double d)              const { return d; }
    NumValue operator()(std::wstring const& s) const
    { 
        try { return boost::lexical_cast<int>(s); }    catch(...) {}
        try { return boost::lexical_cast<double>(s); } catch(...) {}
        throw InvalidParamEx();
    }
};

class CTranslationFunctions
{
    // helper
    NumValue static num(GenericValue const& v) { return boost::apply_visitor(AsNumValue(), v); }
```

There. I defined the missing class for you, and right away added the helper that converts `GenericValue → NumValue`. As you can see, I used `boost::lexical_cast` because there is no use in reinventing the wheel. Note that your earlier approach with `ConvertStringToDouble` had several big problems:

1. it would always result in a `double` value, whereas your functions may require `int`
2. it would treate `'100str1'` as the value `100` without warning
3. it happened at the wrong time: any string a simple `term` would be converted to double, even if it *really* was a string. (*Why this was relevant, will become clear when you see the modified `expr_` and `term_` rules.*)

Let's move on:

```
  public:
    static GenericValue GetSubString(GenericValue const& str, GenericValue position, GenericValue len);
    static GenericValue ConcatenateStrings(GenericValue const& a, GenericValue const& b);
```

Yup, we'll define them later. Now, brace yourself for the *arithmetic operation* functions:

```
#define DEFUNOP(name, expr) private: struct do_##name : boost::static_visitor<NumValue> {    \
        template <typename T1> NumValue operator()(T1 const& a) const { return expr; }       \
    }; \
    public: static NumValue name(GenericValue const& a) { auto na=num(a); return boost::apply_visitor(do_##name(), na); }
#define DEFBINOP(name, infix) struct do_##name : boost::static_visitor<NumValue> {           \
        template <typename T1, typename T2> NumValue operator()(T1 const&a, T2 const&b) const\
        { return a infix b; }                                                                \
    }; \
    public: static NumValue name(GenericValue const& a, GenericValue const& b) { auto na=num(a), nb=num(b); return boost::apply_visitor(do_##name(), na, nb); }

    // define the operators polymorphically, so `int` + `double` becomes `double`, but `int` * `int` stays `int`
    DEFBINOP(Add     , +);
    DEFBINOP(Subtruct, -);
    DEFBINOP(Multiply, *);
    DEFBINOP(Divide  , /);
    DEFUNOP (Negate  , -a);
    DEFUNOP (Sqrt    , sqrt(a));
};
```

***Whoaaaaah*** What happened there? Well, the comment says it all:

- You needed to distinguish between `int`+`int` vs. `double`+`int` etc. This is known as *polymorphic* evaluation. Example: `GetSubString('100str1', 0, 2+1)` could never work, because `2+1` needs to evaluate to an `int(3)`, but your `double Add(double,double)` always produced a `double`.
- I've used MACROs to remove the tedious work from creating a *polymorphic function object* for each operator
- I've let `decltype` detect the resultant types in mixed cases
- Here's where `NumValue` has merit above `GenericValue`: because `NumValue` can only be `int` or `double`, we know that the *generic* `operator()` implementation covers all legal combinations.
- To ensure that all parameters are actually NumValues, they are passed through `asNumeric` before calling the function object.

This thorughly solves your arithmetic operations, and has another bonus: it **removes the 'need' for `ConvertStringToDouble`**, since you get conversion to `NumValue` when it's needed, namely on evaluation of arithmetic operations. *This is an important thing, down the road when we fix your grammar to support your desired input expressions.*

### *If you've come this far, you've seen the rough parts. The rest is plain sailing*.

```
GenericValue CTranslationFunctions::GetSubString(GenericValue const& str, GenericValue position, GenericValue len)
{
    using boost::get;
    return get<std::wstring>(str).substr(get<int>(position), get<int>(len));
}
```

Yeah, I shortened it a bit.

```
GenericValue CTranslationFunctions::ConcatenateStrings(GenericValue const& a, GenericValue const& b) 
{
    std::wostringstream woss;
    woss << a << b;
    return woss.str();
}

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(GenericValue, ConcatenateStrings_, CTranslationFunctions::ConcatenateStrings, 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(GenericValue, GetSubString_      , CTranslationFunctions::GetSubString      , 3)

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(NumValue    , Add_               , CTranslationFunctions::Add               , 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(NumValue    , Subtruct_          , CTranslationFunctions::Subtruct          , 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(NumValue    , Multiply_          , CTranslationFunctions::Multiply          , 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(NumValue    , Divide_            , CTranslationFunctions::Divide            , 2)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(NumValue    , Negate_            , CTranslationFunctions::Negate            , 1)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(NumValue    , Sqrt_              , CTranslationFunctions::Sqrt              , 1)
```

Yawn. We know how to adapt functions for Phoenix, already; **let's get to the grammar definition!**

```
// Grammar to parse map functions
template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type >
struct MapFunctionParser : qi::grammar<It, GenericValue(), Skipper>
{
    MapFunctionParser() : MapFunctionParser::base_type(expr_)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        function_call_ = 
          (no_case["GetSubString"]       > '(' > expr_ > ',' > expr_ > ',' > expr_ > ')') [ _val = GetSubString_(_1, _2, _3)   ]
        | (no_case["ConcatenateStrings"] > '(' > expr_ > ',' > expr_ > ')')               [ _val = ConcatenateStrings_(_1, _2) ]
        | (no_case["Sqrt"]               > '(' > expr_ > ')')                             [ _val = Sqrt_(_1)                   ]
        ;

        string_ = // keep it simple, silly (KISS)
            (L'"' > *~char_('"') > L'"')
          | (L"'" > *~char_("'") > L"'");  

        arithmeticexpression_ =
            term_                  [ _val = _1                  ]
        >>  *( ('+' >> term_       [ _val = Add_(_val,_1)       ])
             | ('-' >> term_       [ _val = Subtruct_(_val, _1) ])
             );                      

        term_ =                      
              factor_              [ _val = _1                  ]
            >> *( ('*' >> factor_  [ _val = Multiply_(_val, _1) ])
                | ('/' >> factor_  [ _val = Divide_(_val, _1)   ])
                );

        factor_ =
                int_               [ _val = _1          ]
            |   double_            [ _val = _1          ]
            |   string_            [ _val = _1          ]
            |   ('-' >> factor_)   [ _val = Negate_(_1) ]
            |   ('+' >> factor_)   [ _val = _1          ]
            |   function_call_     [ _val = _1          ]
            ;

        expr_ = arithmeticexpression_;

        on_error<fail> ( expr_, std::cout
            << phx::val("Error! Expecting ") << _4 << phx::val(" here: \"")
            << phx::construct<std::string>(_3, _2) << phx::val("\"\n"));

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((function_call_) (expr_) (string_) (funcparameter_) (arithmeticexpression_) (factor_) (term_))
    }

private:
    qi::rule<It, std::wstring()> 
        string_; // NO SKIPPER (review)
    qi::rule<It, GenericValue(), Skipper> 
        function_call_, expr_, funcparameter_, // NO LOCALS (review)
        arithmeticexpression_, term_, factor_;
};
```

Well. What have we here. What changed?

- I removed `qi::locals` which was only ever used in the `string_` rule anyways, and I rewrote that to honour the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)
- I also fixed the problem with whitespace in strings (your parser would have parsed `"  oops "` identical to `"oops"`). I did so by removing the Skipper from the `string_` declaration. This has the same effect as enclosing the whole rule in `qi::lexeme[]`.
- I moved `Sqrt` to the `function_call_` rule, because, well, it's a function call.
- I tweaked the function names to be `no_case[]` case insensitive, since your examples suggested that `sqrt(9)` should work
- **Note** that `Sqrt` now takes *any expression* whereas the old situation had

  ```
  | (L"Sqrt" > '(' > double_ > ')') // Wait, whaaat?
  ```

  Yeah, this was never going to parse your second example, really :|

Now the real meat of the operation comes. In order to let `sqrt(GetSubstring(....))` parse, we'll have to let `function_call_` be a possible value for a `term_`. Once that's the case, we don't have to anything more in `expr_` since `expr_` might consist of a single `factor_` containing a single `term_` representing a `function_call_` already, so

```
expr_    = ( *( (function_call_ ^ arithmeticexpression_)| string_ ));
```

evaporates into

```
expr_    = arithmeticexpression_;
```

What happened to `string_` there? Well, it's still in `term_`, where it was, but the `ConvertStringToDouble` was removed there. Strings will just happily be strings, unless they are required in the context of an *arithmetic operation* that requires `NumValue`s. That's when they will be *coerced* into a number, and no earlier (as shown above).

```
int main()
{
    static const MapFunctionParser<std::wstring::const_iterator> p;

    std::wstring input;
    while (std::getline(std::wcin, input))
    {
        std::wstring::const_iterator f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

        GenericValue value;
        assert(qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::space, value));

        if (f!=l)
            std::wcout << L"remaining unparsed: '" << std::wstring(f,l) << L"'\n";

        std::wcout << input << " --> " << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I fed this little test program the two lines from your question, it dutifully churned out the following text:

```
GetSubString('100str1', 0, 2+1) + sqrt(9) --> 103
2 + 3 * sqrt(GetSubString('100str1', 0, 2+1)) --> 32
```

You can see the full code **[on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=01c58619a5d1b4c4ff1a25d3f51d7c7b-f0012dd6f08e49a19d012c2b6dd5ad2d)** (sadly, it takes too long to compile).

---

Originally this answer started with the following:

> **Q.** I have tried to combine 2 grammars as below by using permutation operator. But it doesnt compile

What did you expect the permutation operator to do? [The documentation states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/permutation.html):

> The permutation operator, a ^ b, matches one or more operands (a, b, ... etc.) in any order
> ...
>
> [image]

As you can see it would result in an attribute

```
 boost::variant<
      fusion::vector2<optional<RetValue>, optional<double>>,
      std::wstring>
```

<strike>which clearly is not compatible. Now, I assume you just want *either/or* semantics, so</strike>

```
 expr_    = string_ | function_call_ | arithmeticexpression_;
```

should do nicely, resulting in `boost::variant<RetValue, double, std::wstring>` 
which is assignable to a `RetValue`.

Now after jumping through a dozen hoops to make your sample code compile (why...) here's a fix: